# Ignore property of a property in Xml Serialization in .NET using XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I am carrying out Xml serrialization using `XmlSerializer`. I am carrying out serialization of `ClassA`, which contains property named `MyProperty` of type `ClassB`. I don't want a particular property of `ClassB` to be serialized.

I have to use `XmlAttributeOverrides` as the classes are in another library.
If the property was in `ClassA` itself, it would have been straightforward.

```
XmlAttributeOverrides xmlOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes xmlAttr = new XmlAttributes();
xmlAttr.XmlIgnore = true;
xmlOver.Add(typeof(ClassA), "MyProperty", xmlAttr);

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassA), xmlOver);
```

How to accomplish if the property is in `ClassB` and we need to serialize `ClassA` ?

Comment: I take it you don't want to always ignore the property in `ClassB` for other cases? Otherwise it's as simple as adorning `ClassBy.PropertyToIgnore` with `[XmlIgnore]`?

Comment: yes @ChrisSinclair, you are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it, just update your overrides to point to `ClassB` instead of `ClassA`:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides xmlOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes xmlAttr = new XmlAttributes();
xmlAttr.XmlIgnore = true;

//change this to point to ClassB's property to ignore
xmlOver.Add(typeof(ClassB), "ThePropertyNameToIgnore", xmlAttr);

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassA), xmlOver);
```

---

Quick test, given:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string ThePropertyNameToIgnore { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

And exporting method:

```
public static string ToXml(object obj)
{
    XmlAttributeOverrides xmlOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    XmlAttributes xmlAttr = new XmlAttributes();
    xmlAttr.XmlIgnore = true;
    xmlOver.Add(typeof(ClassB), "ThePropertyNameToIgnore", xmlAttr);


    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassA), xmlOver);
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        xs.Serialize(stream, obj);
        return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
void Main()
{
    var classA = new ClassA {
        MyProperty = new ClassB {
            ThePropertyNameToIgnore = "Hello",
            Prop2 = "World!"
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(ToXml(classA));
}
```

Outputs this with "ThePropertyNameToIgnore" omitted:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ClassA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <MyProperty>
    <Prop2>World!</Prop2>
  </MyProperty>
</ClassA>
```