# How to make XmlSerializer ignore a property in an array to be serialized?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

MSDN gives a good example of how to make the XmlSerializer class ignore a property in a class to be serialized:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributes.xmlignore.aspx

I'm using the XmlSerializer class to serialize an array of objects that inherit from the EntityObject class and I want XmlSerializer to ignore the EntityKey property.  I've written the following code:

```
private void setupXmlSerializer()
{            
    XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    XmlAttributes attributesToOverride = new XmlAttributes();
    attributesToOverride.XmlIgnore = true;            
    overrides.Add(typeof(MyEntityObject), "EntityKey", attributesToOverride);
    completeXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyEntityObject[]), overrides);
}
```

However, when I run my code, I get the same result I was getting before I added the code to ignore EntityKey.  What do I need to do to make XmlSerializer ignore EntityKey for each object in the array to be serialized?

**Edit:** In response to the answer I received, I tried writing the following code:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attributesToOverride = new XmlAttributes();
attributesToOverride.XmlIgnore = true;                        
attributesToOverride.XmlArrayItems.Add(new XmlArrayItemAttribute("EntityKey", typeof(MyEntityObject[])));
overrides.Add(typeof(MyEntityObject), attributesToOverride);
completeXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyEntityObject[]), overrides);
```

When I run this code, I get an exception: `XmlRoot and XmlType attributes may not be specified for the type MyNamespace.MyEntityType`

**Edited Again:** I've written the following code, which runs, but doesn't ignore the EntityKey.  I'm wondering if this could have something to do with the way Entity Framework designs classes.

```
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attributesToOverride = new XmlAttributes();            
attributesToOverride.XmlArrayItems.Add(new XmlArrayItemAttribute("EntityKey", typeof(EntityType[])));
attributesToOverride.XmlIgnore = true;                        
overrides.Add(typeof(EntityType), "EntityKey", attributesToOverride);            
completeXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EntityType[]), overrides);
```

**Edit:** I don't know if this is relevant, but the EntityKey property is declared in the EntityObject abstract class with the following attributes:

```
[DataMember]
[Browsable(false)]
public EntityKey EntityKey { get; set; }
```

There is a second property called EntityState which is declared with XmlIgnore, so I haven't had a problem with having to ignore it.

```
[XmlIgnore]
[Browsable(false)]
public EntityState EntityState { get; }
```

**Edit:** I've made a discovery.  If I try to ignore one of the actual data properties on the EntityObject, it works fine.  I wonder if it could have something to do with either that EntityKey is declared with attributes or that it is a complex type while the other properties are primitive types.

Comment: There is a similar question about ignoring a property of a property, possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947998

Answer (score 0):

You aren't actually specifying what sort of an attribute it is you want to override. Use something like

```
attributesToOverride.XmlArrayItems.Add(new XmlArrayItemAttribute("EntityKey", typeof(MyEntityObject[])));
overrides.Add(typeof(MyEntityObject), "EntityKey", attributesToOverride); // note "EntityKey" here
```

This is important because otherwise it thinks you want to ignore EntityKey on the array itself, but since it doesn't have it it won't ignore it.

--updated to show second line change

Comment: I've tried this, but it still serializes the EntityKey property.

Comment: I suspect it's something like the above post because your code passes in an empty collection of attributes as such none are getting overridden

Comment: Look at the example here, it shows first adding some attributes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c5dw5z7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to attach the override to the **member**, not just the type - there is an `Add` overload that accepts the member-name.

Secondly, it is `EntityObject` that declares this member, and you need to attach the override to the declaring type.

Putting those together:

```
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes attributesToOverride = new XmlAttributes();
attributesToOverride.XmlIgnore = true;
overrides.Add(typeof(EntityObject), "EntityKey", attributesToOverride);
var completeXmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(
      typeof(MyEntityObject[]), overrides);
```

Which then works.